# Dynamically add and remove a Layout when one of the Radio Button is Selected

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlayout

I m able to dynamically add a layout to QHBoxLayout in pyqt , however I m unable to remove them once added.

Main aim is to dynamically add and remove a layout based on the Radio Button selected.

```
def SearchTab(self):

  self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

  button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
  radio_button_1 = QRadioButton("Search")
  radio_button_2 = QRadioButton("Update")
  button_layout.addWidget(radio_button_1)
  button_layout.addWidget(radio_button_2)
  self.layout.addItem(button_layout)

  radio_button_1.toggled.connect(lambda :self.SelectButtonCheck(radio_button_1))
  radio_button_1.toggled.connect(lambda :self.UpdateButtonCheck(radio_button_2))

  self.setTabText(0,"Search")

  self.tab1.setLayout(self.layout)


def SelectButtonCheck(self,b):
    if b.text() == "Search":
        if b.isChecked():
            print(b.text()+ "is selected")
            self.pg_details = pgd.PGDetails()
            layout = self.pg_details.returnLayout()
            self.layout.addLayout(layout)


def UpdateButtonCheck(self,b):

    if b.text() == "Update":
        if b.isChecked():
            print(b.text()+ " is selected")
            for i in  range(self.layout.count()):
                print(self.layout.itemAt(i))
                temp_layout = self.layout.itemAt(i)
                widget = temp_layout.widget()
                temp_layout.removeItem(temp_layout)

                if widget is not None:
                    widget.deleteLater()
```

Initial Screen-

[image]

Currently I m able to add the layout when "Search" Radio Button is selected --

[image: Contains QFromLayout]

But Nothing happens when I select "Update" RadioButton

[image: Nothing Happens here and the application crashed]

Also find the layouts that have been added-

```
for i in  range(self.layout.count()):
print(self.layout.itemAt(i))
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout object at 0x1180ec438>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QFormLayout object at 0x1180ff828>
```

Layouts are being added but not getting removed.

Any leads would be helpful , in what I m missing here

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this. Took me a while but understood what is the arrangement of widgets within the layouts.

I assumed removing the layout will cascade delete the widgets itself.

I used the below function to remove the layout and its widgets corresponding to it.

```
def SearchTab(self):

      self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

      button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
      radio_button_1 = QRadioButton("Search")
      radio_button_2 = QRadioButton("Update")
      button_layout.addWidget(radio_button_1)
      button_layout.addWidget(radio_button_2)
      self.layout.addItem(button_layout)
      #createDB()
      radio_button_1.toggled.connect(lambda :self.SelectButtonCheck(radio_button_1,self.layout))
      radio_button_1.toggled.connect(lambda :self.UpdateButtonCheck(radio_button_2,self.layout))
      #layout.addRow("Address",QLineEdit())
      self.setTabText(0,"Search")

      update_layout = QHBoxLayout()
      #update_layout.set
      #update_btn = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox)
      #update_btn.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
      update_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
      update_btn = QPushButton('Update')
      reset_btn = QPushButton('Reset')
      #self.layout.addRow(update_layout)
      update_layout.addWidget(update_btn)
      update_layout.addWidget(reset_btn)

      update_btn.clicked.connect(self.createDB)

      self.tab1.setLayout(self.layout)

    def SelectButtonCheck(self,b,stacklayout):
        if b.text() == "Search":
            if b.isChecked():
                print(b.text()+ "is selected")
                self.pg_details = pgd.PGDetails()
                layout = self.pg_details.returnLayout()
                self.layout.addLayout(layout)

    def removeLayout(self,layout):
            for i in  range(layout.count()):
                temp_layout = layout.itemAt(i)
                if temp_layout is not None:
                    widget = temp_layout.widget()
                    if widget is not None:
                        widget.deleteLater()
                else:
                    return
                if temp_layout.layout() is not None:
                    self.removeLayout(temp_layout.layout())


    def removeFormLayout(self,layout):

        if layout is not None:

            for i in  range(layout.count()):
                    temp_layout = layout.itemAt(i)
                    if isinstance(temp_layout.layout(),type(QFormLayout())):
                            self.removeLayout(temp_layout.layout())

                    else:
                        next
        else:
            return


    def UpdateButtonCheck(self,b,stacklayout):

        if b.text() == "Update":
            if b.isChecked():
                print(b.text()+ " is selected")
                self.removeFormLayout(stacklayout)
```

The removeFormLayout function picks out the formlayout that I added with the Search radio button and removeLayout removes all the widgets under it as well.

[image]

Open to suggestions and improvements in the method used, I tried it with a couple of layout removals other then FormLayout as well. Currently it is working fine.

Also is anybody aware of how to align the HBoxLayout at the top , the radio button starts from the middle again , I want to align them at the top of the screen

Comment: Instead of eliminating every time layout that is very expensive and nothing clean you could use QStackedLayout where you can have n layouts but only one visible, so you only make visible what you want. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html

Comment: @eyllanesc - Thank you for suggestion , I ll try this. 

I thought QStackedLayout would be better in creating events like Login windows and navigations between different layouts/screens in an application

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do the following.  QWidget and thus QGroupBox have a show/hide option.

**Note**, its best to always hide first, otherwise things get wonky

I have a test function that has the following control logic

```
if isOn:
    self.gb1.hide()
    self.gb2.show()
else:
    self.gb2.hide()
    self.gb1.show()
```

I created a layout that contains both group boxes above.  see the sample logic below.  I am sure there is a way to do this without storing the variables in the window class.

```
    def create_layout(self):
        ly = QHBoxLayout()
        self.gb1 = self.create_gb_test1()
        self.gb2 = self.create_gb_test2()
        ly.addWidget(self.gb1)
        ly.addWidget(self.gb2)
        return ly

    def create_gb_test1(self):
        my_name = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name

        gb = QGroupBox("Find")

        btn_find = QPushButton()

        ly_horiz = QHBoxLayout()
        ly_horiz.addWidget(QLabel("Find:"))
        ly_horiz.addWidget(QLineEdit("Some Text", ))
        ly_horiz.addWidget(btn_find)
        self.ly_find_only = ly_horiz

        gb.setLayout(ly_horiz)
        return gb

    def btn_open_click(self):
        pass

    def create_gb_test2(self):
        my_name = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name

        gb = QGroupBox("View")
        btn_open = QPushButton

        cbo = QComboBox()
        cbo.addItems(['a', 'b'])
        ly_horiz = QHBoxLayout()
        ly_horiz.addWidget(QLabel("Find:"))
        ly_horiz.addWidget(cbo)
        ly_horiz.addWidget(btn_open)
        self.ly_find_only = ly_horiz

        gb.setLayout(ly_horiz)
        return gb
```